# Check User.Identity.IsAuthenticated in ActionFilter right after login

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication, action-filter

I'm basically using the AccountController from the ASP.NET MVC samples. It uses FormsAuthentication to handle the user login. Just to be sure, here is the code to handle user login:

```
    public ActionResult LogOn(string userName, string password, bool rememberMe, string returnUrl)
    {
      if (!ValidateLogOn(userName, password))
      {
        return View();
      }

      FormsAuth.SignIn(userName, rememberMe);


      //Session["userId"] = 1;


      if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
      {
        return Redirect(returnUrl);
      }
      else
      {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
      }
    }
```

As you can see from the commented line, I would like to set a Session variable in this method. However, I figured that it is not the most elegant way of setting a Session variable directly in the controller. It's also inconvenient when unit testing this method (although I could mock it, sure, but still).

So, I figured, I create a custom ActionFilterAttribute that runs after this login routine. If login is succesful, set the session variable in this custom attribute. The code for this is:

```
  public class SetSessionAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
  {
    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext resultContext)
    {      
      if (resultContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
      {
        resultContext.HttpContext.Session["userId"] = 1;
      }

      base.OnResultExecuted(resultContext);
    }
  }
```

The problem is that `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` always returns false until the next "page load". I'm overriding `OnResultExecuted` as I gather that it is the last method to be called in the page lifecycle, but no luck. I also tried `OnActionExecuting`, `OnActionExecuted` and `OnResultExecuting`, but it is always false.

Is there an elegant solution around this? Or should I give up and set the session variable in the controller directly?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with log out because User.Identity.IsAuthenticated was true until next page request but I needed a way to know if user is really finished work with an application.

I think you should set Session or ViewData variable in controller or pass it to another controller via routeValues.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, I could set the session in the controller but that's what I tried to avoid. I still hope there is a viable alternative to it.